# Can't modify response in a Magento event observer, even though observer is firing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm attempting to use an observer to modify the response of the add to cart controller action, but only in the context of an AJAX request.

My observer **is** called and my JS is retrieving data fine, I have verified this by putting a `die()` in my observer function `cartAdd()` and verifying the response developer console, which I am using to see the result of my response from Magento. So JS isn't the issue here.

My primary problem is that I can't seem to modify the response through the normal functions. I get the request by using `$observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getResponse()` and then make changes to it by `setHeader()`, or `setBody()`, or any other function that modifies the response, but there is absolutely no effect to the response!

Does anybody have any clue as to why I'm not able to modify the response in my observer?

In /app/code/local/mynamespace/mymodule/etc/config.xml:

```
<frontend>
....
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_cart_add>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>cartAdd</method>
                </mymodule_cart_add>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

In /app/code/local/mynamespace/mymodule/Model/Observer.php:

```
public function cartAdd(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
    if($controllerAction->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
        $response = $controllerAction->getResponse();
        // I've even tried using:
        // $response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','403 Forbidden'); //using this because i will need it in my final code and it will make it immediatly obvious the response has been changed
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $response->setBody('hello world!!!!');
        // this is to stop the product from being added to the cart
        $controllerAction->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    }
}
```

*Please note: I know this code isn't going to at all AJAXify adding to cart (which is my end goal). At the moment I am just trying to resolve this issue*

I end up just getting the contents of the page that you would end up on as a result of running an add to cart action:

[image: An example of the data I am seeing in the console, as shown to me by my JS code]

Comment: 99% sure that the request is having a different redirect set on it after the dynamic predispatch event is fired. Confirming now, will answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a product is added to cart there is admin-configurable behavior to send a person to the cart page or to redirect them back to the product page. See the **System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart: After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart** field.

This redirect behavior is accomplished via a redirect which will displace any redirect set in the dynamic `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` event; [ref. the final bit of logic](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#L209) from the `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()`. Have no fear, though! Magento core developers have the need to override this behavior as well, so it is possible to inform the **Mage_Checkout** cart controller's `addAction()` method to bypass the normal redirect behavior if a flag has been set on the `checkout/session` object. Not only is there a hook and supporting logic to make it work, but there is actually a working example from the core - always a good thing for developers.

Just prior to the final redirect logic in the `addAction()` method, the cart controller's `addAction()` method dispatches the [`checkout_cart_add_product_complete`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#L205) event. [This event is observed](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/etc/config.xml#L87) by the **Mage_Wishlist** observer. A quick review of [relevant final logic](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Observer.php#L137) from the `Mage_Wishlist_Model_Observer::processAddToCart()` method shows how to prevent the cart controller's `addAction()` method from redirecting - namely by setting the `no_cart_redirect` flag on `checkout/session` object, which preserves the redirect set on the response object.

There is one more consideration in this case. It's likely that the **Mage_Wishlist** observers behavior should be preserved, namely: after adding a product to cart from the wishlist, a customer may be redirected to the next product in their wishlist. This is one of the instances when observer processing order matters. To make sure that the **Mage_Wishlist** module's add to cart behavior is preserved, other modules which consume the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event should fire before the **Mage_Wishlist** observer. In the declaration file for the custom module, the Mage_Wishlist module should be set as dependent on the custom module, which will ensure that the custom module's observer will fire before the **Mage_Wishlist** module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_Module>
        <Mage_Wishlist>
            <depends>
                <Custom_Module />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Wishlist>
    </modules>
</config>
```

If the **Mage_Wishlist** module were not a factor, the better targeted event to consume would be the dynamically-generated `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_add` event, which is the last targeted event before the generic `controller_front_send_response_before` event.

Comment: Really useful information thanks! I've also noticed the events get completely bypassed when not logged in, but that may be something specific to my environment. `customer/session->authenticate()` gets called somewhere and redirects to the login page without consulting the `no_cart_redirect` flag. This is OK though as not being able to add to the cart unless logged in is intended in my case. I'll just make the frontend behave differently. Thanks again

Comment: @benmarks great answer as always. Btw I don't get it: `$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)`. What is the meaning of args `true` ? Looks like the flag `no_redirect_flag` only set / get as data in `Varien_Object`, as I don't find it explicitly defined as `attribute` in the `checkout/session` model. Am I right?

Comment: @ivantedja the session models have a modified getter. By passing in true the value is retrieved and then the property is unset.

Comment: @benmarks oh ok, I see. Never thought it would be modified. Thanks, I'm learning new things (should have checked all possibilities next time)

Comment: @ivantedja I rarely open up my IDE without learning something new about Magento :-)